# How to get AHK to pause the script when chrome is not in focus and resumes when it is?

Tags: google-chrome, autohotkey

This script is supposed to press Z every 50 um..units of time when I press Q until I press W.
What I have trouble doing is making it pause(stops pressing z) whenever chrome is not in focus and resumes when it comes back into focus again.

Thank you. Below is the script that does what I said in the first sentence.

```
q::
    stop = 0
    Loop 
    {
        SendInput, z
        Sleep 50 ;adjust for speed of repetition
        if stop
            break
    }
    return


w::
    stop = 1
    return
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a WinWaitActive command after the sleep command.